# Email Program issues

Tags: c#, email, batch-file, robocopy

I work for a company and I was asked to write some script that would do a robocopy of a destination, then email the log with the subject being either failed or success. After a quite a bit of research I could not figure out why my program keeps breaking, and it's breaking in an odd way as well.

The script consists of a batch script and a c# application to send the email.

RobocopyScript.cmd

```
@echo off


set robocopydestination=\\[computer]\guest\TESTFOLDER\
set robocopysource=C:\Users\[username]\Script
set robocopylogoutput=log.log


set mailfrom=[email address]
set mailto=[email address]
set successsubject=Robocopy Success
set successbody=Robocopy successfully completed its backup.
set failuresubject=Robocopy Failure
set failurebody=Robocopy failed to complete its backup
set networkcredentialusername=[email address]
set networkcredentialpassword=[password]
set logfile=log.log

robocopy %robocopysource% %robocopydestination% /e /z /tee /log:%robocopylogoutput%
if errorlevel 1 goto success
if errorlevel 0 goto success
goto fail

:fail
EmailProgram.exe %mailfrom% %mailto% %failuresubject% %failurebody% %networkcredentialusername% %networkcredentialpassword% %logfile%
exit

:success
EmailProgram.exe %mailfrom% %mailto% %successsubject% %successbody% %networkcredentialusername% %networkcredentialpassword% %logfile%
exit
```

EmailProgram.csx

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace EmailProgram
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {                                   // from     To       Subject  Body
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            //set up the smtp client
            client.Port = 25;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";                     //ncu      ncp
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(args[4], args[5]);

            //add 4 lines of space between the body message and the log information for readability
            mail.Body += "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n----------------\r\nLOG START:\r\n----------------";

            //break up the log file into its lines, then write the lines to the email message body
                                                          //log file path
            string[] logLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(args[6]);
            foreach(string s in logLines)
            {
                mail.Body += s;
            }

            //send the email, if the email fails to send it simply will close this application
            try
            {
                client.Send(mail);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On running the batch script, robocopy finishes successfully, then as it tries to run EmailProgram.exe it gives me:

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\[username]\Script\CompleteProjects\RobocopyEmail\completed'.

I'm definitely no expert, but I see nowhere in my code that calls the path that the exception gives. Could someone please help me figure this out because i'm stumped after several hours of trying to figure this out. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the path for the log file?

Comment: Personally id ditch robocopy and just use System.IO, and reduce the complexity, however this is likely not your current problem

Comment: the log file is simply the directory that the script and executable are in, i've tried making the path C:\Logs\log.log as well with the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are spaces in the variables `successsubject` etc.

When you call `EmailProgram.exe %mailfrom% %mailto% %successsubject% %successbody% ...`, you really emit the call

```
EmailProgram.exe apa@bepa.com qux@foo.bar Robocopy Success Robocopy successfully completed its backup...
```

So `completed` becomes `args[6]` in the emailer.

Try

EmailProgram.exe "%mailfrom%" "%mailto%" "%successsubject%" "%successbody%" ...

instead.

Comment: Well that hit like a smack to the face. Thank you so much, a few quotes and it worked like a charm.